# Save file in same document set it is opened from

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-object-model, excel

I have a request from a customer I am struggling with. Given is the following scenario:

SharePoint Server 2016

Whenever a new document set is created a specific Excel file is added to the document set. This Excel file is contains internal information. At a certain point the file should be made available for externals also. To do so, the file should be saved with a different name in the same document set it was opened from and some columns will be removed.

I can save a file to a document set via the client object modell. What I am missing is how to retrieve the filename and path of the file initially opened in order to save the manipulated file to the same location.

Any ideas?

Best regards,

Markus